# Best Pythonic Data Structure for Cross-Tabulated Data

Tags: python, data-structures

I am writing some Python scripts to analyze and retrieve cross-tabulated data collected from a large number of nominal categories.  As an example, think about data from a large number of zip-codes, where each zip-code is cross-tabulated by an age bin (about 8 bins) and a gender bin (2 bins).

Functionally, I can achieve everything I need using a dictionary that has zip-code as the key, and a list of lists as the value.  However, this solution is a bit stark.  Nothing in the data structure itself indicates which cross-tab goes where, i.e. when working with the code, you have to scroll back and forth (or rely on comment) to determine if age is the inner list or the outer list, etc.  And for future applications, I will be deals with 4 or 5 cross-tabbed variables.

In c, this could generally be solved by combining arrays with structures, so that names of the structure members help keep everything organized, i.e. ptrZipCodeEntry->AgeBin[2].Male = 1000. Fully realizing this is more about style than substance, my question is: What is the best pythonic practice for this situation?

Comment: Perhaps you could include an example of the type of data you need to model in a structure, and what sort of operations need to be performed.

Comment: The type of data is integer counts. The main operations are subtractions, additions, and multiplications need to construct statistical quantities like chi-squared values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to help with cross-tabulation. Pandas is a database management library that is commonly used in python for data manipulation work such as cross-tabulation.

Looking at the example given in their [cross-tabulation documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), we can see that if you have 3 arrays of data:

```
a = array([foo, foo, foo, foo, bar, bar,
   bar, bar, foo, foo, foo], dtype=object)
b = array([one, one, one, two, one, one,
   one, two, two, two, one], dtype=object)
c = array([dull, dull, shiny, dull, dull, shiny,
   shiny, dull, shiny, shiny, shiny], dtype=object)
```

You can do a cross-tabulation of

`crosstab(a, [b, c], rownames=['a'], colnames=['b', 'c'])`

```
b    one          two
c    dull  shiny  dull  shiny
a
bar  1     2      1     0
foo  2     2      1     2
```